# Adding a percentage sign to a number field in Excel

Tags: excel, number-formatting

We have an Excel file that has a column `Percentage`. This column contains numbers and as such is capable of sorting from large to small and reverse. The only thing missing is that it's not displaying a percentage sign after the number.

What we have is this:

[image: Picture]

It would be great if it could show the following and still be able to sort from small to big:

```
114,87 %
50 %
81 %
91 %
```

Whatever I try in the formatting option `Custom`, I always end up with trailing zero's or changed values.

Comment: You need to change the formula so that it divided by 100 to give a proper decimal number, then use the standard % format

Comment: I rather not do that, because I use the value in PowerShell to take some decisions.

Comment: Divide value by 100 and change cell format to percentage.

Comment: @DarkLite1 you need to change number of decimal point to 0 when you choose percentage format for cell.

Comment: Is the cells formulas or only values?

Comment: @Andreas only values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Format these cells with custom format `?\%`

Comment: This is the best answer yet, but then `114,87` becomes `115%`, and I would like it to be `114,87 %` (with a space, keeping the 2 digits, but not when there are trailing zeros `81` > `81 %`).

Comment: I don't think you can have any format that changes based on significant digits.  You have have 114,87% and 115,00%, or you can have them both showing as 115%.  Why do you need the accuracy of a fifth significant digit in a percentage?

Comment: True, I'll accept this as the correct answer. Thank you guys, appreciate it :)

Comment: Is the comma in `114,87` a thousand separator? why not `11,487`? If you want `11487`(within no comma or within a valid  thousand separator) to be `11,487 %`, you can use a custom format `#,### \%`

Answer (score 2):

Adding answer to add image with result. Column B can be removed completely, but i have it just to show it working. Column B = A/100. Column C is formatted as percentage with 0 decimal places.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Format these cells with custom format ?\%

I tried commenting and editing the accepted answer to no avail.

In anycase... using the custom format:

```
?.??\%
```

yeilds results closer to what the OP was asking for I think, however I haven't been able to retain the space he was requesting.

Answer (score 0):

A space between the value and the percent sign may achieved by using Custom format:

0,00" "%
or
0.00" "%
depending on the decimal separator used in your country.

The missing space in the standard Excel percentage format is a bug in Excel since the stone age.